# Strict search using mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli

I am pretty much stuck for hours on this and Would appreciate if someone could help .

I am doing a mysql search on data :

> Row Id             List Data
>   
>   1                   3,2,7,11
>   
>   2                   1,27
>   3                   2,17,44
>   
>   4                   19,77

My problem is I want to do a strict search .

Lets say i want to search for rows which have '7' in above data .

If i do :

> select id from table where list_data like '%7%'

will obviously return all 4 rows

I want to get only 1st row as my result .

How can i achieve that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No Ben limit will not work as that data may be in any row not just first . This is just a sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` function (there is a sample in another answer) or regex instead:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE list_data REGEXP '(^|,)7($|,)'
```

however, it seems that you're trying to put several data links to one field. If so, then avoid that - because it violates relation DB principles. Use linking table instead and then your query will be rewritten using [SQL JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) operator.

Answer (score 4):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select id from table 
where find_in_set(7, list_data) > 0
```

BTW you should normalize your data to avoid such problems in the future. Please store always only 1 value in a column, not multiple.

Comment: + Forgot about `FIND_IN_SET()`. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your table **format** is wrong. It have to be

```
id Data
1  3
1  2
1  7
1  11
2  1
2  27
3  2
3  17
3  44
4  19
4  77
```

and query

```
select id from table where data = 7
```

Comment: Yes i know but that how it was designed . Design Flaw it is i know :(

Comment: Oh, you don't know it yet. You will know it when you get your data and/or traffic.